# Celsius and Fahrenheit converting with choices

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I am trying to make a Python program where you choose if you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. Here is the program:

```
x = (raw_input("would you like to convert fahrenheit(f) or celsius(c)?"))
if x == "f":
 y = (raw_input("what is the fahrenheit?"))
 f = (int(y) - 32) * 5.0 / 9
print f

if x == "c":
 n = (raw_input("what is the celsius?"))
 z = (int(n) *9) / 5 + 32
 print "and in fahrenheit, that is:"
 print z
```

I tried to change `if x == "c"` to `elif x == "c"`, but it gave me a `TextError`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Just indent `print`:

```
x = raw_input("would you like to convert fahrenheit(f) or celsius(c)?")
if x == "f":
    y = raw_input("what is the fahrenheit?")
    f = (int(y) - 32) * 5.0 / 9
    print f
elif x == "c":
    n = raw_input("what is the celsius?")
    z = (int(n) * 9) / 5.0 + 32
    print "and in fahrenheit, that is:"
    print z
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to either remove that:

```
print f
```

call, or move it afterwards, or indent it, since the elif has to come immediately after the if block, and with the print statement indented the way it is, it ends the if block.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way can be:

```
x = (raw_input("would you like to convert fahrenheit(f) or celsius(c)? "))
if x == "f":
    y = (raw_input("what is the fahrenheit?"))
    f = (int(y) - 32) * 5.0 / 9
    print "and in celsius, that is: ",
    print f
elif x == "c":
    y = (raw_input("what is the celsius?"))
    f = (int(y) *9) / 5.0 + 32
    print "and in fahrenheit, that is: ",
    print f
else
    print "Error"
```

Comment: This will always print "Error". You are missing `else` before `print "Error"`.

Comment: `else` with no : following is a SyntaxError. Been coding in Lua recently ? ;)

Answer (score -1):

Do the followings bro (include"def cel_fah(C):" as well)

def cel_fah(C):

```
'''
Takes in temps in celsius and gives them out in fahrenheit
'''

F=abs(C*9/5+32)

print(f'{C}°celsius is equal to {F}° fahrenheit')
```

then you can easily call the fuction and get the result like I do now(you can pass in what ever number for celsius in () )

{for degree sign(°) you can use alt+248}

cel_fah(0)

0° celsius is equal to 32.0° fahrenheit

hope I could have been some help. **;)**